# Chopping the last sequence of a pattern

Tags: perl

I have this series of values

```
rd_8KB_rms
rd_8KB_rms_qd1
rd_8KB_wh
rd_8KB_wh_q1
rd_8KB_wms
rd_8KB_wms_qd1
rd_256K_rms
rd_256K_rms_1
```

and where there are 3 underscores I would like to chop the last underscore and the characters that trail it ( which are variable in number). I think I have tried variations of substr, split, regex but can't find anything that works

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and then we can go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use transliteration `tr/_//` to count the number of underscores and substitution `s/_[^_]*$//` to remove the part from the last underscore to the end.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/_[^_]*$// if tr/_// == 3;
    say;
}

__DATA__
rd_8KB_rms
rd_8KB_rms_qd1
rd_8KB_wh
rd_8KB_wh_q1
rd_8KB_wms
rd_8KB_wms_qd1
rd_256K_rms
rd_256K_rms_1
```

If there can be even more underscores, use a variant like

```
    s/_[^_]*$// until tr/_// <= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That seems really elegant although I'm just wondering how to read these values back into a variable.  What I mean by that is an input file is parsed and the strings shown in data are the contents of a variable called $var ( for arguments sake).  If $var currently has value rd_8KB_rms_qd1  how do I re-work the tr statement so that the new value is rd_8KB_rms  ?

Comment: Just bind the var: `$var =~ s/_[^_]*$// if $var =~ tr/_// == 3;`